# How/Where to display contextual information based on radio button check

Tags: selection, multi-selection, radio-buttons

I have a list of countries where the user can select one by toggling a radio button. Each country has a unique cost in the local currency which the user needs to be aware of.

What is the best way to display this information?

- Consider information clutter and readability
- Mobile usage
- Long list of countries
- General usability issues

Possible option below. Cost displays when checked within same row highlight as country.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7RWXz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Could you provide more details? Would the cost affect any decision making (as for what city to choose), or the user selects first and then need to be informed of some price?

Comment: @Izhaki Sure. The cost should not influence any decision. However, the user should be aware that the consequence of their decision will result in being charged the shown cost.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a different bolding (as you did) but posting the information below the city to make it stand out from the heading city. Like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1BAU3.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

It would also be rendered better on mobile devices since the columns doesn't have to be that wide as in your suggestion.